# Converting stringified float to float in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a mapping in an Elasticsearch index with a certain string field called `duration`. However, `duration` is actually a float, but it's passed in as a string from my provisioning chain, so it will always look something like this : `"0.12"`. So now I'd like to create a new index with a new mapping, where the `duration` field is a float. Here's what I've done, which isn't working at all, either for old entries or for incoming new ones.

First, I create my new index with my new mapping by doing the following :

```
PUT new_index
{
  "mappings": { "new_mapping": {"properties": {"duration": {"type": "float"}, ... }
}
```

I then check that the new mapping are really in place using :

```
GET new_index/_mapping
```

I then copy the contents of the old index into the new one :

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "old_index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_index"
  }
}
```

However, when I look at the entries in `new_index`, be it the ones I've added with that last `POST` or the new ones that came in since through my provisioning chain, the `duration` entry is still a string, even when its `_type` is `new_mapping`.

What am I doing wrong here ? Or is there simply no way to convert a string to a float within Elasticsearch ?

Comment: how are you copying the contents from old index to new index. Are you parsing the type to proper form before posting it to new index. Since your old index has string value, copying the same content will keep the same string type for new index. Please demonstrate how are you copying.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken my `POST _reindex` is what's copying my content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duration field in the new index will be indexed as float (as per your mapping), however if the duration field in the source document is still a string, it will stay as a string in the `_source`, but still be indexed as float.

You can do a range query "from 1.00 to 3.00" on the new index and compare with what you get in the old index. Since the old index will run a lexical range (because of the string type) you might get results with a duration of 22.3, while in the new index you'll only get durations that are really between 1.00 and 3.00.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, when I try to use something like `Line chart` in Kibana's `Visualize` panel, the field is treated somewhat oddly. On the one hand, it's listed as an option as a field on which something like an average aggregation is possible, but on the other whenever I try to do anything with it I'm told that `fielddata` is disabled by default on text fields. Is there no way to just get this field to behave like a float in general ?

Comment: Can you define "whenever I try to do anything with it" ? Did you make sure to refresh your index pattern? What field type do you see in your index pattern for the duration field?

Comment: Yes I've refreshed it. The entry is marked as a `number` and is both `searchable` and `aggregatable`. What I mean is that when drawing a line chart for example, while I can select `duration` as my Y-field, as soon as I ask Kibana to produce the plot I get the following error message : `Visualize: Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [duration] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory.`

Comment: Hmmm... Things seem to be working now. I think I must have refreshed my index at the wrong time or something along those lines. Thanks for the help.